# Particles except Flames in Render mode

Tags: rendering

I have a problem with the render mode. I dont have flames like in the Solid mode, but Particles.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you setup flame material? Show flame nodes.

Comment: Material is set up incorrectly. Attribute for the fire is called "flame", no "flames" were expected. If you want to create one for you use Quick Smoke command from Object menu.

Comment: Are you kidding me I changed the name to flame and the fire appeared. I thought that the name isnt that important, because it is "just" a name. -.-